# Problem with loading TIFF image on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, tiff

I have a bucket on Google Storage with tiff images. What am I doing wrong?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff")
im
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff'
```

Gsutil shows:

```
!gsutil ls gs://bucket/train_images/ | head -10
gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/000920ad0b612851f8e01bcc880d9b3d.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/0018ae58b01bdadc8e347995b69f99aa.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/001c62abd11fa4b57bf7a6c603a11bb9.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/001d865e65ef5d2579c190a0e0350d8f.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/002a4db09dad406c85505a00fb6f6144.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003046e27c8ead3e3db155780dc5498e.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/0032bfa835ce0f43a92ae0bbab6871cb.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003a91841da04a5a31f808fb5c21538a.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003d4dd6bd61221ebc0bfb9350db333f.tiff
```

I can even make an attempt to read image using pandas and the same path:

```
df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket/train_images/0018ae58b01bdadc8e347995b69f99aa.tiff")
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 49, saw 2
```

Imread returns different error:

```
import tifffile as tiff
a = tiff.imread("gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff.tif")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gs:/bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff'
```

Should I or can I switch somehow to /gs: ?

@@@ 
Locally I have the same problem.

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket/train_images/ | head -10
gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/000920ad0b612851f8e01bcc880d9b3d.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/0018ae58b01bdadc8e347995b69f99aa.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/001c62abd11fa4b57bf7a6c603a11bb9.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/001d865e65ef5d2579c190a0e0350d8f.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/002a4db09dad406c85505a00fb6f6144.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003046e27c8ead3e3db155780dc5498e.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/0032bfa835ce0f43a92ae0bbab6871cb.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003a91841da04a5a31f808fb5c21538a.tiff
gs://bucket/train_images/003d4dd6bd61221ebc0bfb9350db333f.tiff
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Trying PIL:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/---/Desktop/gcloud/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2766, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/train_images/0005f7aaab2800f6170c399693a96917.tiff'
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python
```

Comment: Could you please follow this [Cloud Storage Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#reading_from_cloud_storage) about reading/writing to Cloud Storage and let me know if you were able to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is here, but when I need to read something from a GS bucket, I just make the file (usually the whole bucket) publicly readable, and then pass in the usual `https` link. It has never failed me.

Comment: Well, this could be a solution... What about memory and efficiency? The dataset is quite large, over 350GB.

Comment: @Ironwing the method I am suggesting just changes some permissions, so should not affect memory and efficiency at all. However, if you are using the free colab, it will probably run out of resources on a dataset that big.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, I will probably need to read images in blocks, but still I can't undestand why PIL library can't open that tiff file.. How can I read tiff image using this library with http link?

Comment: @Ironwing Just use the public url instead of the `gs` URL (I assume that it will be the same, with `gs` replaced by `https`).

Comment: @Ironwing but again, you have to make it public first.

Comment: Made bucket publicly readable, I can download single image from https link, but PIL still crashes with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory :(